# Mean stack grunt showing some error 'function name()' was used before it was defined

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, mean-stack

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

```
   modules/codes/client/config/codes.client.config.js
      6 |    function menuConfig(menuService) {
                                ^ 'menuConfig' was used before it was defined.
   modules/codes/client/config/codes.client.routes.js
      6 |    function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
                                 ^ 'routeConfig' was used before it was defined.
     58 |    function getCode($stateParams, CodesService) {
                             ^ 'getCode' was used before it was defined.
     65 |    function newCode(CodesService) {
                             ^ 'newCode' was used before it was defined.
   modules/codes/client/controllers/codes.client.controller.js
     11 |  function CodesController ($scope, $state, $window, Authentication, code) {
                                    ^ 'CodesController' was used before it was defined.
     22 |    function remove() {
                            ^ 'remove' was used before it was defined.
     29 |    function save(isValid) {
                          ^ 'save' was used before it was defined.
     42 |      function successCallback(res) {
                                       ^ 'successCallback' was used before it was defined.
     48 |      function errorCallback(res) {
                                     ^ 'errorCallback' was used before it was defined.
   modules/codes/client/controllers/list-codes.client.controller.js
     10 |  function CodesListController(CodesService) {
                                       ^ 'CodesListController' was used before it was defined.
   modules/codes/client/services/codes.client.service.js
     11 |  function CodesService($resource) {
                                ^ 'CodesService' was used before it was defined.

>> 11 errors in 99 files
```

I create an **MEAN Stack Applications** using **Mongodb,Express, yo meanjs, nodejs, grunt** and I create a module using **yo meanjs:crud-module myModuleName**, it's created and also showing on app menu, but when I'm running grunt command it's showing above error in terminal and browser console return 404 error. Here is my code..

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('codes').run(menuConfig);
menuConfig.$inject = ['Menus'];

function menuConfig(menuService) {
    // Set top bar menu items
    menuService.addMenuItem('topbar', {
        title: 'Codes',
        state: 'codes',
        type: 'dropdown',
        roles: ['*']
    });
    // Add the dropdown list item
    menuService.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'codes', {
        title: 'List Codes',
        state: 'codes.list'
    });
    // Add the dropdown create item
    menuService.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'codes', {
        title: 'Create Code',
        state: 'codes.create',
        roles: ['user']
    });
}
```

}());

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem with the generator. 
The linting error you are seeing is defined [here](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#latedef)

To bypass it you should find the jshint config file (usually named .jshintrc), find the line
    `"latedef" : true,` 
and change it to 
    `"latedef" : "nofunc",` or add it if it doesn't exist.

In my opinion hoisting is more dangerous for variables than for functions so this should be a safe operation.